# C++ Class Variable Integer got different value

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to make a simple Library Service Program

Class Code

```
class bookEntry {
public:
int copies;
char name[30];
char author[30];
};

class library {
public:
bookEntry database[50];
int numBooks = 0;

void insertBook (char bookName[], char author[], int c); // Add
void deleteBook (char bookName[]);  // Delete
//bookEntry *search(char bookName[]);   // Not worked yet
void print(void);     // Print_List
};
```

Main Code

```
void library::insertBook(char bookName[], char author[], int c) {   // AddBook
int i, j;
cout << bookName << author << c;
for (i = 0; i < numBooks+1; i++) {
    string a = (database[i].name);      // Compare Book Title
    if ((a.compare(bookName)) == 0) {           // If it's same
        database[i].copies += c;                // add to copies and pass
        break;
    }
    else {
        database[numBooks].copies = c;
        strcpy(database[numBooks].name, bookName);       // Add New Book
        strcpy(database[numBooks].author, author);
    }
}
numBooks += 1;
}

void library::print(void) {                     // Print Books
cout << "BookName        Author        Copies" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i <= numBooks; i++) {
    cout << database[i].name << "   " << database[i].author << "   " << database[i].copies << endl;
    }
}
```

`Numbooks` = Total counts for different types of books

And I got result got right on the first value on array of `bookEntry`.
But when i put another values, the number(`copies`) got different number then i inserted. Also, did worked well when i putted values that i inserted before.
LIKE
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYWBv.jpg)

Why is this happening? Did i put variables wrong?

Source : [Main_File](https://gist.github.com/roamgom/0d7c33b1e59263f12906da6167bcd594)

Comment: Is `numBooks` supposed to be the number of distinct books, or the total of all copies of the books?

Comment: You need to step through the code with your debugger, and watch what happens as the insert code handles the second book.

Comment: @PhilM It's for Total counts for Different types of books

Comment: @PhilM I watched result for inserting second book and more. If you check on Result Image (Link) That's the result that i got. The number didn't go into arrays well.

Comment: Did you go through the entire function for the 2nd book? Every iteration of the loop?

Comment: Please show your test code and not just the "library" code. Ie, your main function or the function that is actually calling your insertBook function.

Comment: I'll add link... the comment is written in korean... Although it will work well..

Comment: As an aside: please initialise your variables. `int copies = 0;` `char name[30]` = {};` etc... Might even fix your error if you're lucky. Also, since this is C++, please consider using `std::string` instead of char arrays and `std::vector` instead of fixed size arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Stepping through the code should with the debugger should show you this:

You are checking if each book matches the one you're adding, and then, for **every** iteration that the comparison fails, updating the name and copies for the newly entered book.

This means, you compare against the first book, it fails, so you add the second. Then, you compare against the (newly-added) second book, see that it does match, and update the number of copies again. There's a reason the number of copies displayed for the 2nd book is exactly twice the number you entered.

What you need to do is check each existing copy, and then, only after all the existing books have been checked, and the book not found, add the new one.